# WPF DataGrid bound to entity framework doesn't update after change of data in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

I'm working on a WPF-application in which i have bound a datagrid to entity framework.

This is my datagrid definition:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="grd_formula_arguments" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource commonControlStyle}" IsReadOnly="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding FormulaArgumentsAndFields, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_attribute_name" Binding="{Binding attribute_name}" Header="Argument"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_assigned_field_name" Binding="{Binding assigned_field_name}" Header="Feld"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The ItemsSource is bound to a property in the viewmodel, which is a list of my entity formula_field_attributes.
That entity contains the columns attribute_name and assigned_field_name.
This is the viewmodel property:

```
public List<formula_field_attributes> FormulaArgumentsAndFields
{
    get { return formulaArgumentsAndFields; }
    set
    {
        formulaArgumentsAndFields = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FormulaArgumentsAndFields");
    }
}
```

At the beginning the list only contains attributenames and assigned_field_name is blank.
Then i can assign a fieldname to an attribute in the list.

```
        var argumentname = ((formula_field_attributes)grd_formula_arguments.SelectedItem).attribute_name;
        foreach (var item in changeTextProperties.FormulaArgumentsAndFields)
        {
            if (item.attribute_name == argumentname)
            {
                item.assigned_field_name = fieldName;
            }
        }
        changeTextProperties.RaisePropertyChanged("FormulaArgumentsAndFields");
```

When i take a look to the viewmodel property after my operations, it looks fine.
But i can't see my changes in the datagrid.
What did i wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Interface INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented. The same as the method RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: After you manipulate data in your collection call `RaisePropertyChanged("FormulaArgumentsAndFields");` that way your UI knows it has changed.

Comment: @XAMIMAX I tried RaisePropertyChanged("FormulaArgumentAndFields") but the content of the datagrid doesn't change. Is it possible that i have to use ObeservableCollection instead of List?

Comment: Use a OberservableCollection<formula_field_attributes> no List<formula_field_attributes>.... it is the correct way.

Comment: @Wolfgang Feneberg:
I tried this too, but no positive result.

Comment: That's not the correct way of using `CollectionViewSource`! First in xaml `<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding FormulaArgumentsAndFields}" x:Key="formulaArgList"><CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="someProperty"/>            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions></CollectionViewSource>` then `<ListView.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource inpsections}}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile i resolved the problem by the following steps:

1. I changed the type of the viewmodel property to ObeservableCollection.
2. I made a change in the set-method. I create a new ObservableCollection-object, get the items from the VM-property, set the assigned_field_name i want and - finally i set the VM-property with the new object.

I know it's not what i should do, but it works.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? It avoids changing the underlying collection type, keeping your code compatible with the rest of your VM code and it only changes how UI handles the collection.

Comment: @XAXIMAX: Yes i tried ObservableCollection and i let that change in my code, because it's definitely the better choice. But the datagrid don't actualize, even when i call the method RaisePropertyChanged. Very curious.